# Postgres - DBLINK - How it works?

Tags: postgresql, view, dblink

I have a DBlink that performs a select on a specific table in a remote database.
As this remote table is very large, I need to make a filter (using where) to bring very few lines to the local database.
The connection between local database and remote database is made through a 4G data link that has a monthly data traffic limit.
I had been experiencing huge data consumption and was not understanding why.

Yesterday I decided to do a test. I created a View in the remote database with only the necessary data (already applying the where that was previously applied in DBLink). 
I rewrote the query via DbLink, at this time pointing to the remote View and without any where.

The result was a reduction in data consumption.

The impression it gives is that Select via Dblink performs a select * on the remote table, brings all the data and then applies the where in the local database, causing excessive consumption.
When I segment the data in the View, this no longer occurs.
Does anyone have any explanation for this case?

Below is the select that I perform:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('cloud',
                        'select     field1,
                                field2,
                                field3
                        from    my_table
                        where   field1  = 2 
                        order by    field1
                        limit 50'   
            )
            AS rep( field1  int4,
                    field2  int4,
                    field3  int4
            );
```

Another test I did was to perform a backup of the data from the remote table and delete most of the data leaving only the data used in DBlink.
Consumption has also dropped again confirming my theory that Postgres brings all the data and only performs the filter on the local database.

Comment: Nowadays foreign tables are preferred over DBlink - and `postgres_fdw` can push  down those conditions.

Comment: Your example is not valid.  The query needs to be quoted.

Comment: sorry @jjanes, my fault when I wrote the question. I just made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

dblink just hands the query as written to the other side.  It certainly does not strip out the WHERE or LIMIT.  I don't know what is actually going on, but your theory presented here can't explain it.

To verify my assertion, you can set log_statement = 'all' on the foreign side and observe what query is actually getting run.

Comment: the most intriguing is that in Postgres documentation, the examples that are given always have the Where clause outside the original select. There is none with the clause inside.
See the example of the documentation below:  `` SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=postgres options=-csearch_path=',
                     'select proname, prosrc from pg_proc')
  AS t1(proname name, prosrc text) WHERE proname LIKE 'bytea%'; ``   
Anyway, I will follow your suggestion.